# Does the Azure iot device sdk support multiple devices connecting at the same time?

Tags: java, azure, azure-iot-hub

I'm trying to write a little application that simulates many devices connecting and sending messages via MQTT protocol to an iot hub using the azure iot-device-client sdk version: 1.3.31. Eventually this will be multi-threaded and it will have thousands of simulated devices connecting simultaneously. This doesn't seem possible with the device client sdk. Can the device sdk be used this way?

```
IotHubClientProtocol protocol = IotHubClientProtocol.MQTT;

List<String> conns = new ArrayList<>();
//conns.add() 10 times with correct connection strings    

conns.forEach((newConnString) -> {
    try {
        DeviceClient client = new DeviceClient(newConnString, protocol);

        client.open();
        System.out.println("connected - "+newConnString);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

When I run this I get every other device connecting with the rest getting forcably disconnected with this error:

> java.io.IOException: Unable to subscribe to topic :devices/sim_3/messages/devicebound/# because java.io.EOFExceptionConnection lost
>       at com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.transport.mqtt.MqttIotHubConnection.open(MqttIotHubConnection.java:140)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.transport.mqtt.MqttTransport.open(MqttTransport.java:83)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.DeviceIO.open(DeviceIO.java:212)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.DeviceClient.open(DeviceClient.java:197)
>       at com.company.Main.lambda$main$0(Main.java:49)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
>       at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:45)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Rita's answer, I do recommend to use for each simulated MQTT device own AppDomain and lightweight (raw) MQTT Client Library (e.g. [M2Mqtt](https://www.nuget.org/packages/M2Mqtt/)). 
This concept has been used in the [Azure IoT Hub Tester](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1173356/Azure-IoT-Hub-Tester), where each MQTT Device is isolated, hosted, subscribed and published in own AppDomain. The following screen snippet shows 30 virtual MQTT Devices connected to the Azure IoT Hub:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For MQTT protocol, it is not supported connecting multiple devices over the same TLS connection concurrently.

> [IoT Hub only supports one active MQTT connection per device. Any new
>   MQTT connection on behalf of the same device ID causes IoT Hub to drop
>   the existing connection.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support)

For your use case, you can choose AMQP. It supports connection multiplexing across devices.

Ref: [choose a communication protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-protocols).

Comment: I was under the assumption that each DeviceClient would make a separate mqtt connection as I do supply different deviceId/credentials for each. Also, we would like to access device twin and methods messaging which isn't supported via AMQP.